# How to prevent from cutting off layout's text by the Android's Softkeys

Tags: android

I'm new to App development but I think I'm slowing getting the hang of it.  I've created different xml layouts for different devices.  I've gotten rid of the action bar.  However, I can't seem to get rid of the side bar on certain Android devices, and they cut off text as a result.

How do I get rid of the bar on the right of my attached image?  I've tried

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

to no avail.

[image: Nexus 10 sidebar issue]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide Your xml layout code and format it.

Comment: My apologies for not doing so.  My issue has been resolved (see Har Kal's answer below).

Comment: There are no answer below.